# How to insert NULL character in std::wstringstream?

Tags: c++, std, stringstream

I need to construct a multi-string (`REG_MULTI_SZ`) in C++ from a list of values represented in a `std::vector<std::wstring>`.

This is what first came to mind but was of course incorrect:

```
std::wstring GetMultiString(std::vector<std::wstring> Values)
{
    std::wstringstream ss;

    for (const std::wstring& Value : Values) {
        ss << Value;
        ss << L"\0";
    }

    ss << L"\0";

    return ss.str();
}
```

Upon inspection, the returned string didn't have any embedded NULL characters.

Comment: `ss << L"\0";` is same as `ss << L"";` and does nothing. The both point to null-terminated char literals, how much nulls are there after the first one, doesn't matter

Comment: @273K Yeah, I am aware of that, but it is very easy to make a mistake hence the Q&A. I wonder if using C++ string literals (`L"\0"s`) would behave differently?

Comment: "As expected"?  You wouldn't be asking the question if that was the expected result.

Comment: Yes, `L"\0"s` is a string containing the zero char.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is actually quite simple:

```
std::wstring GetMultiString(std::vector<std::wstring> Values)
{
    std::wstringstream ss;

    for (const std::wstring& Value : Values) {
        ss << Value;
        ss.put(L'\0');
    }

    ss.put(L'\0');

    return ss.str();
}
```

The reason why the original code failed to accomplish anything is that `ss << L"\0";` is the same as `ss << L"";` and therefore does nothing.

You can also pass `0` instead of `L'\0'`:

```
        ss.put(0);
```

Or use `<<` and [std::ends](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/ends):

```
        ss << std::ends;
```

Or use `<<` and C++ string literal [operator""s](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s):

```
        using namespace std::string_literals;
        // ...
        ss << L"\0"s;
```

Or even [basic_ostream::write](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write):

```
        const wchar_t Null = 0;
        // ...
        ss.write(&Null, 1); // sizeof(Null) / sizeof(wchar_t)
```

Comment: To make this answer better you should explain why the original code failed and how this approach fixes it.

Comment: The fix here is in single-quotes. You could use `put` or continue using `operator<<`; doesn't matter.

Comment: alternatively, `ss.write` which is an unformatted write

Comment: @NathanOliver I updated the question as per your suggestion.

Comment: Add that to the answer, not the question.  The question states the problem and the answer explains it and how to fix it.

Comment: @NathanOliver Reading comprehension faiil on my end, hopefully this fixes it.

Comment: @anatolyg I prefer `put()` since it is more clear that you are putting a single character in the stream and you can't use wrong quotes.

Comment: Note that you don't have to use a character constant `L'\0'`, you could just use `0`.

Comment: @MarkRansom Good point, but I don't think being more explicit hurts.

Answer (score 4):

There's an obscure manipulator in the standard library for this too:

```
ss << std::ends;
```